# Error using $compile angujar.js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, pug

I'm working on a project with angular.js. I have a problem when compiling.

In the previous version of the program it showed the table with the data (when `currentProduct` was a single variable). But now I am using a array and the array does not compile well.

Does it have anything to do with it, was once a normal variable and is now an array of variables?

Error:

[image]

I am using this method to add a new div.

```
// trae los datos de la tabla
Product.getPriceTable({id:product.id},function (result) {
  product.hasPriceTable = true;
  product.priceTable = result.priceTable;
  var directive = '<div editable-price-table price-table="currentProduct[product.id].priceTable" product="currentProduct[product.id]" user="currentUser"  />';
  var linkFn = $compile(directive);
  var content = linkFn($scope);
  angular.element('#price-table-' + product.id).append(content);
});
```

The error is in the variable directive.

The code does not compile in this line:

```
var linkFn = $compile(directive);
```

Comment: Can you show where `product` is declared? Is it attached to the scope?

Comment: this is a terrible way to add new content to your page.  You should program against your DATA instead of programming against the DOM with angular.  use `ng-repeat`, `ng-if`, or similar to allow angular to deal with the DOM instead.  appending content this way is the JQuery way of thinking.

Comment: I am defining currentProduct: `$scope.currentProduct = [];`